# Possibility to combine pagination with infinite scrolling

Tags: primeng-turbotable

Is there a way in primeng-turbotable to combine pagination with infinite scroll? This is e. g. possible in ngx-datatable: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#virtual-paging.